# why with tkinter reading gpio input gives same value regardless whether switch is pressed or not

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi3

I have a raspberry pi 3 and have created a tkinter GUI in python and in the background I'm polling a GPIO input connected to a switch for value change. However, the program keeps reading the same value of 1 regardless whether switch is pressed or not. I have tried two ways of polling the gpio, the after method tkinter root and using another Thread and yet same results. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import time
from threading import Thread
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import logging
import os

cwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
logger = logging.getLogger('Door Sensor')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s')
file_handler = logging.FileHandler(os.path.join(cwd, "message.log"))
file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)


def sensor_setup():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setup(29,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)


class Mainwindow():

    def __init__(self):
        self.sensorState = None
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("Switch Monitor")
        self.frame = Frame(self.window)
        self.frame.grid()
        self.window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.window.config(cursor="none")
        self.window.attributes('-zoomed', True)
        self.window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
        self.show_idle_closed_switch()
        t = Thread(target = self.switch_monitor)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()



    def show_idle_closed_switch(self):
        self.welcomeLabel = ttk.Label(self.window, text="Switch Closed",font='size, 16', justify='center', anchor='center')
        self.welcomeLabel.grid(columnspan=8,row=1, pady=15)



    def show_switch_opened(self):
        self.welcomeLabel = ttk.Label(self.window, text="Switch Opened",font='size, 16', justify='center', anchor='center')
        self.welcomeLabel.grid(columnspan=8,row=1, pady=15)


    def forget_welcome_label(self):
        self.welcomeLabel.grid_forget()


    def switch_monitor(self):
        while True:
            self.sensorState = GPIO.input(29)
            logger.info('sensor value = %s\r\n' % str(self.sensorState))
            if self.sensorState == 0:
                logger.info('Door Closed, sensor value = 0\r\n')
                print("Front Door Closed")
            elif self.sensorState == 1:                   
                logger.info('Door Opened, sensor value = 1\r\n')
                print("Front Door Opened")
                self.forget_welcome_label()
                self.show_switch_opened()

            self.sensorState = None
            time.sleep(45)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sensor_setup()
    w = Mainwindow()
    w.window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help and I'm just letting the would be beneficiary from this know that i found what the problem is in the code. Replace GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM), with GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) and now the program runs as is intended.